# error "TypeError: element.type is undefined" isMuiElement

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a form in react using material-ui, but I am getting this error when I import element from material-ui.

here is the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AWhH.png)

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import{Button, TextField} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function Info() {
return (
    <div>
        <TextField label="First name" margin="normal" variant='outlines' color= 'secondary'/>
        <TextField label="First name" margin="normal" variant='outlines' color= 'secondary'/>
        <TextField label="First name" margin="normal" variant='outlines' color= 'secondary'/>
        <Button variant='contained' color='primary'>Next</Button>
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you modify Textfield attribute value.
variant="outlines" -> variant="outlined"

Comment: thank you I just modified it, but it is still throwing me the same error... Am I importing the elements properly? I always do it like this but I don't know...

Comment: I have another question: I am using a persistent drawer that only hides on mobile version, however my page content is hidden behind it. How do I ensure that my content is always center ? thank you 

here is the screenshot 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBrPO.png

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly because I'm not good at English. If your question is how to display center the content, you should give the parent element display:"flex"; alignItems:"center"; justifyContent:"center". If the answer is not something you were question, please ask me again.